# Injecting factory class to other beans

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have a factory class and I wonder if it is possible to inject the `AnimalMapper` factory class into other beans that needs it?

*AnimalMapper factory class*

```
public static Mapper create(final String type) {
    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("dog")) {
        return new DogMapper();
    } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("cat")) {
        return new CatMapper();
    } ...
}
```

Currently I am using `AnimalMapper.create(...)`

Comment: I am totally unclear on the question here. If you want to inject the mapper, do so. What is stopping you?

Comment: FYI, a better design might be to use an `enum` for `type`

Comment: Also I don't understand why to inject something with a public static factory method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code

```
public class TestClass{
   //member variable defination. 

   @Inject
   AnimalMapper animalMapper; //defining mapper instance
}
```

I am not sure if you are looking for this but if you can clarify question more then can add more details.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve? Something like this with CDI:

```
public class TestClass{

    @Inject @Any
    Instance<Mapper> mapper;

    public void myMethod(){
        if(isCat()){
            mapper.select(new AnnotationLiteral<Cat>(){}).get();
        }

        if(isDog()){
            mapper.select(new AnnotationLiteral<Dog>(){}).get();
        }
    }

}

@Dog
public class DogMapper implements Mapper...

@Cat
public class CatMapper implements Mapper...
```

Answer (score 0):

See the reference documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/pdf/spring-framework-reference.pdf

Pages 43-43 on factory-method in your bean definition.